# Can't append numpy arrays after for loop?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, loops, numpy

After a for loop, I can not append each iteration into a single array:

in:

```
for a in l:
arr = np.asarray(a_lis)
print(arr)
```

How can I append and return in a single array the above three arrays?:

```
   [[ 0.55133  0.58122  0.66129032  0.67562724  0.69354839  0.70609319
      0.6702509   0.63799283  0.61827957  0.6155914   0.60842294  0.60215054
      0.59946237  0.625448  0.60215054  0.60304659  0.59856631  0.59677419
      0.59408602  0.61021505]
    [ 0.58691756  0.6784946  0.64964158  0.66397849  0.67114695  0.66935484
      0.67293907  0.66845878  0.65143369  0.640681    0.63530466  0.6344086
      0.6281362   0.6281362   0.62634409  0.6281362   0.62903226  0.63799283
      0.63709677  0.6978495]
    [ 0.505018  0.53405018  0.59408602  0.65143369  0.66577061  0.66487455
      0.65412186  0.64964158  0.64157706  0.63082437  0.62634409  0.6218638
      0.62007168  0.6648746  0.62096774  0.62007168  0.62096774  0.62007168
      0.62275986  0.81362 ]]
```

I tried to append as a list, using numpy's append, merge, and hstack. None of them worked. Any idea of how to get the previous output?

Comment: What's the structure of `a_lis`? Its `len`, and the `len` of all sublists?  Of `shape` of the elements if they are arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) to join the arrays:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4]])
b = np.array([[5, 6, 7, 8]])

arr = np.concatenate((a, b), axis=0)
print(arr)
# [[1 2 3 4]
#  [5 6 7 8]]
```

---

**Edit1:** To do it inside the array (as mentioned in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47122770/cant-append-numpy-arrays-after-for-loop#comment81195501_47122827)) you can use [`numpy.vstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html):

```
import numpy as np

for i in range(0, 3):
    a = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=4)
    if i == 0:
        arr = a
    else:
        arr = np.vstack((arr, a))

print(arr)
# [[1 1 8 7]
#  [2 4 9 1]
#  [8 4 7 5]]
```

---

**Edit2:** Citing [Iguananaut](https://stackoverflow.com/users/982257/iguananaut) from the comments:

> That said, using concatenate repeatedly can be costly. If you know the
>   size of the output in advance it's better to pre-allocate an array and
>   fill it as you go.

Comment: Thanks for the help, however how can I do it in the for loop?

Comment: Run on loop's list output: `arr = np.concatenate(a_lis)`

Comment: I got `ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated`

Comment: Any idea of what to do @ksal ?

Comment: I added another way to do it inside the for loop.

Comment: That said, using concatenate repeatedly can be costly. If you know the size of the output in advance it's better to pre-allocate an array and fill it as you go.